# How do I calculate Base64 conversion rate?

Tags: signature, password-hashing, encoding

Basically I need to have a base64 encoded signature that has to be 96 characters long. However, I do not know what length I need to have the signature at so when I encode it, it can be that exact size. Does anyone know how to convert it? Also, does anyone know how to convert it in base64 encoding or any byte size encoding?

Comment: you might be interested [Why does base64 encoding require padding if the input length is not divisible by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4080988/1820553)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I do not know what length I need to have the signature at so when I encode it, it can be that exact size.

Well, base64 uses 4 characters (from an alphabet of size 64) to encode 3 bytes (3 bytes contain 24 bits; `24/4 = 6` bits per base64 character).

Hence, if the signature was 72 bytes long, that would translate to `(72/3)*4 = 96` characters you require.

Now, base64 typically has a === trailer to signify the end of the encoding; are you counting that?

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for clearing it up poncho.

Comment: _Some_ base64 (mostly PEM and MIME and derivatives thereof) has _padding_ which can be 1 or 2 equalsign but never 3, and is not present if the input is an exact multiple of 3. PGP 'armor' does have a trailer with 1 equalsign _followed_ by 4 base64 chars (exactly) encoding CRC24.

Comment: Per [Base64](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-4), $b>0$ byte(s) encode to $c=4\,\left\lceil b/3\right\rceil$ characters ending in $n=2-(b+2\bmod 3)=(-b)\bmod3$ time(s) the character `=`. And for decoding, $c$ characters with $c$ multiple of $4$, ending in $n$ times the character `=` with $0\le n<3$, decode to $b=3\,c/4-n$ byte(s).

Comment: [Can Base64 encoded string end with 3 equal signs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42052364/1820553). No!

Answer (score 0):

base64 is defined on [rfc4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4)

As poncho mentions, it has an overhead of 33%, and thus 96 / 4 × 3 = 72 bytes needed

Comment: In this answer, it is meant _bytes_ where there now is _characters_.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed. Thanks @fgrieu